# JavaScript Convention for Default Function Return Value?

Tags: javascript, function, return, return-value

Hello Human Resources,

In JavaScript, what is the convention for the default function return value? I was taught that every function should return a value.

I was following suit with C, and returning 0, but that's falsy in JavaScript, and so it doesn't really make sense when a function has successfully executed.

I asked The Google, but no conclusive answer.

Some other candidates that I had in mind:

- 1
- `true`
- Just accept the system default of `undefined`

What do you think?

Comment: A Computer Science professor in College taught this. @bits: sorry, of you're a programmer, you are. @Niet: On successful completion, methinks that alert should return `true`, or possibly `1`.

Comment: Ask your professor what the `void()` function should return.

Comment: Why the down vote? Type `alert(1)` into the console of your favorite browser, and--despite successful execution--you will see a return value of `undefined`. Better return result here would be `true`, no?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a convention, but if you want to add returns to void functions or procedural function just return true.